# Why does Google says that an item needs an url property in schema.org?

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

When I put an example from the [ItemList page](https://schema.org/ItemList) in the [Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool) by Google, it says that an `item` needs an `url` property.

The example:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context": "http://schema.org",
      "@type": "ItemList",
      "name": "Top 5 covers of Bob Dylan Songs",
      "itemListOrder": "http://schema.org/ItemListOrderAscending",
      "numberOfItems": 5,
      "itemListElement": [
        {
          "@type": "ListItem",
          "position": 5,
          "item": {
            "@type": "MusicRecording",
            "name": "If Not For You",
            "byArtist": {
              "@type": "MusicGroup",
              "name": "George Harrison"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
</script>
```

I simplified it to have a minimal example, but the error is the same with the exact example from the page.

I tested this code and there is no error here:

```
{
    "@type": "ListItem",
    "position": 5,
    "item": {
         "@type": "MusicRecording",
         "name": "If Not For You",
         "byArtist": {
             "@type": "MusicGroup",
             "name": "George Harrison"
         }
     }
}
```

Can anybody explain this to me?

Comment: If the SDTT reports missing properties, it only means that they are missing for getting one of Google’s rich results. Is this the answer you are looking for? ("You can ignore the error.")

Answer (score 0):

A ItemList in general is a list collection of sites like a breadcrumb, overview of bandsites, etc.
If you only want a list without links to deatils sites you can use only ListItem with Items.  This is the different of your samples ItemList and ListItem.